# Controlling when boost mode is used in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, heatmap

I have included boost.js module in my app. This enables boost mode by default based on certain thresholds. I want to control when the boost mode kicks in for a heatmap. I found below 3 options. The documentation is a bit confusing. What is the difference between these options? Which one(s) should I use if want boost mode to be always enabled irrespective of number of data points?

1. [plotOptions.series.turboThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold)
2. [boost.seriesThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/boost.seriesThreshold)
3. [plotOptions.series.boostThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.boostThreshold)

Answer (score 3):

## 1. [plotOptions.series.turboThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold)

This setting has nothing to do with the boost module, as the API states, this only applies to series where data is configured as an array. And will speed up those cases without needing the boost module:

> When a series contains a data array that is longer than this, only one dimensional arrays of numbers, or two dimensional arrays with x and y values are allowed. Also, only the first point is tested, and the rest are assumed to be the same format. This saves expensive data checking and indexing in long series. Set it to 0 disable.

## 2. [boost.seriesThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/boost.seriesThreshold)

This setting enables boost mode based on number of series present. Regardless of how many points are in each series.

> Set the series threshold for when the boost should kick in globally.
>
> Setting to e.g. 20 will cause the whole chart to enter boost mode if there are 20 or more series active. When the chart is in boost mode, every series in it will be rendered to a common canvas. This offers a significant speed improvment in charts with a very high amount of series.

## 3. [plotOptions.series.boostThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.boostThreshold)

This is the series type specific or global setting. You can make this apply to one series type, or all series types.

> Set the point threshold for when a series should enter boost mode.
>
> Setting it to e.g. 2000 will cause the series to enter boost mode when there are 2000 or more points in the series.
>
> To disable boosting on the series, set the boostThreshold to 0. Setting it to 1 will force boosting.

## 4. [series.seriesType.boostThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.boostThreshold)

This is the local version of 3. Here you can apply boost to a specific series.

---

If you want to always use boost mode you set 3. like stated in the API:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      boostThreshold: 1
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

**JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/bxkqv38a/1/